# Replace or trim string in SQL

Tags: sql, string

I'm pretty good at SQL but I haven't done this in a while.

I have a simple table with a common string:

```
TableName = ExampleTable1
ColumnName = ExampleColumn1
```

I have a string like this:

```
MYSTRING_10_TB_EXAMPLE1
MYSTRING_120_TB_EXAMPLE2
```

I have this query:

```
select ExampleColumn1, replace(ExampleColumn1,'MYSTRING_', '') from ExampleTable1
```

This is returning just the number at the beginning of the string:

```
"10_TB_EXAMPLE1"
```

I now need to remove the string after the first dash after the integer.  The integer could be either one digit or four or five but I need everything including the first "_" removed or anything that starts with "_TB" to return only the integer.

I know you can use STUFF and replace. I think I need to replace my third parameter in the query of '' with another replace or right maybe?

I have tried many things here and I can't trim the whole string after the first "_" sign to just leave the integer.

Comment: Look at the `SUBSTRING` function. And BTW please use Markdown to format your question (eg. putting code inside code markers etc.) to make it more readable.

Comment: Chris, as you can see it would have been important to state the RDBMS. One answer is for MySQL, the other one for SQL Server. Please edit your question and state the correct tags, thx!

Comment: Hi sorry about that.  Isn't substring a certain number of characters?

Comment: So which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Hi Chris, as you are new to SO, please be aware, that the professionals giving answers here, are hungry for reputation points. Please go through the answers and vote them up if they are helpful. If one of them helped you to solve your problem, you should mark it as the accepted answer, Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `REPLACE` to trim away the first part of the string as you've already done.

Use `CHARINDEX` to find (in the resulting string) the position of the first `_`

Then use `LEFT` to keep only the left part of the string up to (but excluding) the first `_`

```
SELECT
    ExampleColumn1,
    LEFT( REPLACE(ExampleColumn1,'MYSTRING_', ''),  
       CHARINDEX( REPLACE(ExampleColumn1,'MYSTRING_', ''), '_' ) - 1
    )
FROM 
    ExampleTable1
```

Would return

```
MYSTRING_10_TB_EXAMPLE1      10
MYSTRING_120_TB_EXAMPLE2     120
```

If you're using mySql instead of `CHARINDEX` use `LOCATE`:

```
LOCATE( '_', REPLACE(ExampleColumn1,'MYSTRING_', '') ) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function.
This query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX('MYSTRING_120_TB_EXAMPLE2','_',2),
  '_', -1);
```

will return `120`

Comment: As far as I know there's no STUFF function in MySQL. As the OP mentions this function I'd suppose the issue is with SQL Server... That's for the OP to clearify...

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string in its parts and continue whatever you want. Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(aString VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('MYSTRING_10_TB_EXAMPLE1')
                      ,('MYSTRING_120_TB_EXAMPLE2');

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(aString,'_','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS SingleWords
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT SingleWords.value('x[1]','varchar(max)') AS part1
      ,SingleWords.value('x[2]','int') AS part2
      ,SingleWords.value('x[3]','varchar(max)') AS part3
      ,SingleWords.value('x[4]','varchar(max)') AS part4
FROM Splitted 

/* Result
part1       part2   part3   part4
MYSTRING    10      TB      EXAMPLE1
MYSTRING    120     TB      EXAMPLE2
*/
```

Just a short explanation: The underscore is replaced by `"</x><x>"`. With the opening `"<x>"` at the beginning and the closing `"</x>"` at the end this is XML. Each node is addressable with its index. That's it...